# Poco XML - Get node inner XML

Tags: c++, xml, poco-libraries

I've got the following example XML:

```
 <root>
   <node id="1">
      <value>test</value>
      <value2>test2</value2>
   </node>
   <node id="2">
      <value>test</value>
   </node>
 </root>
```

How can I get the entire node 1 XML content inside an std::string?

I've tried the following:

```
Poco:XML:Node *node = xmlDocument->getNodeByPath("/root/node[1]");
Poco::XML::XMLString xstr = node->getPocoElement()->innerText;
string str = Poco::XML::fromXMLString(node->getPocoElement()->innerText);
```

And it will returns this:

```
test \n test2
```

I need this:

```
   <node id="1">
      <value>test</value>
      <value2>test2</value2>
   </node>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not exist such function in Poco, but you can create own with minimum lines of code. 
Information about methods of Node you can get in [documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.XML.Node.html).

You need concatenated name of node with attributes with name and value by sub-nodes. 
For get attributes use method [attributes](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.XML.Node.html#29091).

For get sub-nodes use method [childNodes](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.XML.Node.html#29086).

Complete example:

```
#include "Poco/DOM/DOMParser.h"
#include "Poco/DOM/Document.h"
#include "Poco/DOM/NodeList.h"
#include "Poco/DOM/NamedNodeMap.h"
#include "Poco/SAX/InputSource.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::string node_to_string(Poco::XML::Node* &pNode,const std::string &tab);

int main()
{
std::ifstream in("E://test.xml");
Poco::XML::InputSource src(in);
Poco::XML::DOMParser parser;
auto xmlDocument = parser.parse(&src);
auto pNode = xmlDocument->getNodeByPath("/root/node[0]");

std::cout<<node_to_string(pNode,std::string(4,' '))<<std::endl;

return 0;
}

std::string node_to_string(Poco::XML::Node* &pNode,const std::string &tab)
    {
    auto nodeName = pNode->nodeName();

    Poco::XML::XMLString result = "<" + nodeName ;

    auto attributes = pNode->attributes();
    for(auto i = 0; i<attributes->length();i++)
    {
    auto item = attributes->item(i);
    auto name = item->nodeName();
    auto text = item->innerText();
    result += (" " + name + "=\"" + text + "\"");
    }

    result += ">\n";
    attributes->release();

    auto List = pNode->childNodes();
    for(auto i = 0; i<List->length();i++)
    {
    auto item = List->item(i);
    auto type = item->nodeType();
    if(type == Poco::XML::Node::ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        auto name = item->nodeName();
        auto text = item->innerText();
        result += (tab + "<" + name + ">" + text + "</"+ name + ">\n");
    }

    }
    List->release();
    result += ("</"+ nodeName + ">");
    return Poco::XML::fromXMLString(result);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I can't believe there's no such method already buit-in it's so usefull.